# Capybara not running custom classes (POROs)

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, selenium, capybara, factory-bot

For one of my forms, I created a plain-old-ruby-object to provide data for a select form.

```
class SearchFields
  def types
    Card.select(:types).order('types ASC').uniq.collect.each do |c|
      if c.types.nil?
        next
      else
        types = c.types.delete("[:&,\"]").split().join(" ")
        [types, c.types]
      end
    end
  end
end
```

In my controller, I call the method like so:

```
def index
  @card_types = SearchFields.new.types
end
```

And in my view (which is a partial):

```
<%= f.label :types_cont, "Type" %>
<%= f.select :types_cont, @card_types, {include_blank: true} %>
```

And here is my spec:

```
feature "User uses Advanced Card Search", js: true do
  let!(:card) { create(:card) }

  background do
    visit cards_path
    expect(page).to have_content("Search for cards you would like")
    click_on "Advanced Search"
    fill_in("cards_autocomplete_name", with: card.name)
    select(card.cmc, from: "q_cmc_gteq")
    select(card.cmc, from: "q_cmc_lteq")
    select(card.colors, from: "q_colors_cont")
    select(card.types, from: "q_types_cont") # here is where it fails
    fill_in("q_printings_cont", with: card.printings)
    select(card.legalities, from: "q_legalities_cont")
    click_on "card-search-submit"

    expect(page).to have_css("#cards-table td#card-name")
  end

  scenario "and successfully finds card" do
    expect(page.first('#cards-table td#card-name').text).to eq(card.name)
  end
end
```

I'm running Capybara with Selenium to run my test, but when the partial gets rendered, the select form doesn't contain any data. The `Card` object is created using FactoryGirl and I know that it has been created successfully, because the previous test works.

What seems to be happening is that the SearchFields object is not being created. If I type @card_types in my console, it returns `nil`. 
Does anyone know what is happening here and why the object isn't being created? Any info would greatly be appreciated! :)

**UPDATE:**
Here is the database_cleaner.rb file:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|

  config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
  end

  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
  end

  config.before(:each, :js => true) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
  end

  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end

  config.after(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end

end
```

Comment: Are you sure the Factory is creating something in the types attribute of the Card? Also is this your first js: true test, or do you have other js tests working correctly?

Comment: Please make shure your tests aren't ran in database transaction. In this case any changes in database (any new records in tables) aren't seen in a thread of the test web server.

Comment: @TomWalpole The types attribute is successfully created. I tested it with `pry` as well to make sure. And, this is my second `js: true` test. The test before this one tests the "Basic Search" functionality, and it completes successfully.

Comment: As @andrykonchin commented, make sure you've got database_cleaner set up correctly to use truncation rather than transaction based cleaning and that you've disabled transactional fixtures. If you're using transaction based testing then testing with pry in the test thread isn't actually showing you what the app sees

Comment: I've added the database_cleaner config to the post. As far as I can tell - since it's running `js: true` - it is using `:truncation`. Does it matter that `:transaction` is run where `js:` is not set to `true`?

Comment: It's fine for non-js tests to use transaction (as long as you don't use after_commit callbacks in your code). Have you changed to config.use_transactional_fixtures=false in your Rspec config?

Comment: @TomWalpole Yes, I have. It is set to `false`